# How to not to add an app.config automatically when a webservice reference is added

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How to not to add an app.config automatically when a webservice reference is added in visual studio project

Comment: Use a Service Reference instead.

Comment: That's not going to avoid changing the App.Config. The reference's URL is added to the App/Web.config as soon as you add the reference. I'm not sure there's actually a way to do what OP says.

Comment: With what alternative? That you're immediately creating for yourself a maintenance issue because the URL is hard-coded?

Comment: Why would you get rid of it?

Comment: because there is the risk that the url of the web reference is got from app.config instead of from a database(as i want from database)